# Firebase Realtime Database - Intermittently update() works like set()

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Intermittently and unpredictably, the Firebase Realtime Database `update()` function seems to work like the `set()` function.  Anecdotally, it appears to happen on about 1% of update operations.  But we've performed extensive logging, and will see things happen like a particular update is being pushed out to a group of users inside of a loop, we verify that correct information is being sent to all of them in the logs, and `update()` is being called on each record.  However, the outcome we'll see is that sometimes one of the users will wind up with a record that only contains the fields we updated, and all other fields in the record get deleted, while all other users receive the update properly.  Running the exact same `update()` operation subsequently will result in everything updating as expected.  Is this a known issue?  Are there any workarounds?  We are running firebase-admin 6.0.0 on Node 8.14.0

Attempted multiple repeated tests of the update() function.  There is no surefire way to cause this issue to reproduce, but it is happening randomly in production.

```
const contactsRef = admin.database().ref().child('contacts');
...
//targetUID, contactID, contactObj get passed in via PubSub
...
contactsRef.child(targetUID).child(contactID).update(contactObj);
```

Expected: `update()` should only update the record fields being passed to it.

Actual:  `update()` seems to work like `set()` randomly, about 1% of the time.  Any fields that are not included in the object being passed to `update()` are deleted from the target record in the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very unlikely that the database server behaves differently for 1% of your users. Much more likely it that there is a slight difference in the calls that that 1% of your users makes. It's hard to be certain what that difference is from the code you shared, so below is an educated guess in hopes of unblocking you quickly.

You say you do:

> ```
> contactsRef.child(targetUID).child(contactID).update(contactObj);
> ```
>
> Expected: `update()` should only update the record fields being passed to it.

It's a bit subtle and unfortunately you don't show how you construct `contactObj`. So I'll give an example. Say that you start with JSON:

```
"uid1": {
  "name": "unknown",
  "id": -1,
  "full_name": "unknown",
  "metadata": {
    "last_seen": "20 minutes ago",
    "reputation" 56
  }
}
```

And you run this on that location:

```
ref.update{
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721
}
```

In this case only the `name` and `id` properties under `ref` are updated. The other properties are unmodified, so you end up with:

```
"uid1": {
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721,
  "full_name": "unknown",
  "metadata": {
    "last_seen": "20 minutes ago",
    "reputation" 56
  }
}
```

But now say that you also want to update the `metadata/reputation`. You might think that this works:

```
ref.update{
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721,
  "metadata": {
    "reputation": 61
  }
}
```

But here you are telling the database to replace `metadata` with the object you provided. So the result is:

```
"uid1": {
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721,
  "full_name": "unknown",
  "metadata": {
    "reputation" 61
  }
}
```

And this means that `last_seen` is now gone from the database.

To update a nested property, include its full path in the key. So:

```
ref.update{
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721,
  "metadata/reputation": 61
}
```

And with that, you'll keep `metadata/last_seen`, while updating `metadata/reputation`:

```
"uid1": {
  "name": "miles_b",
  "id": 2687721,
  "full_name": "unknown",
  "metadata": {
    "last_seen": "20 minutes ago",
    "reputation" 61
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, we have performed extensive logging to ensure that at the point where the update() function is being called, correct information is being passed into it.  This is not happening consistently for any particular users, but rather happening randomly across all users.  Performing the exact same update a minute or two later can result in proper expected behavior.  What is happening when this error occurs is that any fields that are not specifically included in the update call, are deleted from the record in the database.

Comment: As usual: it will be a lot easier to help if you show the minimal complete details of the problem. I get that showing us how to reproduce this may be hard/impossible, but showing the standalone code and the logging that shows that it's not doing what is expected should be possible. If it's not, I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they may be able to look at your project for oddities. They too though will typically ask for code+logging first, unless they've seen multiple reports